# how to getting the count with all records

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I am trying this mongodb aggregation. I got the output but how can I get the count value with all records.

```
db.STREETLIGHTS.aggregate(
[
{$match : {"CreateDate":{$gt:new Date(ISODate("2018-04-09T23:54:16.064Z") - 24*60*60 * 1000)}}},
{ $project: {_id:1, SLC_ID:1,LONGITUDE:1,LATITUDE:1,DCUID:1,CUMILITIVE_KWH:1,LAMPSTATUS:1,CreateDate:1 } },



 ]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
db.STREETLIGHTS.aggregate([
  {$match : {"CreateDate":{$gt:new Date(ISODate("2018-04-09T23:54:16.064Z") - 24*60*60 * 1000)}}},
  {$project: {_id:1, SLC_ID:1,LONGITUDE:1,LATITUDE:1,DCUID:1,CUMILITIVE_KWH:1,LAMPSTATUS:1,CreateDate:1 } },
  {$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}}}
 ])
```

Comment: @ Yuanhang iam trying this code i got count value my requirement is count value with project fields please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `$sum` operator in the `$project` stage :

```
{$project: {
    // Your others projections
    total: {$sum: 1}
}
```

Comment: iam trying this  {$project: {
 
    total: {$sum: 1}
}
but not getting the out put

Comment: @ Nicolas  iam trying this  {$project: {
 
    total: {$sum: 1}
}
but not getting the out put

Comment: @  Nicolas 3.4.4

Comment: Normally it should work, try add a `$group` at last stage : {$group: {total: {$sum: 1}}}

Comment: @  Nicolas using {$group: {total: {$sum: 1}}   sorry not working

Comment: When you say it's not working, you have an empty result or an error ?

Comment: @  Nicolas  some error like   Error:
Assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "a group specification must include an _id",
 "code" : 15955,
 "codeName" : "Location15955"

Comment: ah ok I see, add `_id: null` before `total` in the group stage

Comment: @     Nicolas    i got the total records count {
    "_id" : null,
    "total" : 1859.0
}
but not getting records my requirement is count with records please suggest me

Comment: @  Nicolas count is ok but not getting project fields...please help me

Comment: put your `$project` stage at the end of the aggegation pipeline, and add to the project : total: "$total" to keep the result of the group stage

Comment: Please refrain from having a discussion in comments, or embedding additional details. This is an ideal case for [Stack Overflow Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com).